# Pdf image issues in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I installed pdfcatalog plugin from http://www.magazento.com/english/magento-ext/magazento-extensions/free-pdf-export in magento. It generates pdf of product detail page but the quality of product images are getting blurred. Could you please tell me how to resolve it and how to ensure that pdf contain images of atleast 150 to 300 dpi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the source images available to the pdf-generator are not the originals, it works off just the same thumbnails as you see on normal browser.

The trick is to get rid of the zoom tool on the pages and show a different media file.

One way to do this is to check the $_REMOTE address and, if it is the same as $_SERVER address show a different media.phtml, one with no gizmos, just the image in supa-dooper-high-quality. This could also be tied into the print stylesheet - look how that gets included and use the same approach for your media.phtml selective loading.

*You may need to roll your own PDF generator.*

The wkhtml2image program might be useful - you can use it to create a very neat PDF. You'll also be able to make sense of it in a way that isn't so easy with third party extensions.